# Where is IsInstanceOfType or its equivalent in new .Net Type/TypeInfo API?

Tags: c#, portable-class-library, system.reflection, base-class-library

I've read the [Evolving the Reflection API blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/08/28/evolving-the-reflection-api.aspx) and I've converted most of the code I was using when I had an "old" API included in my PCL but I haven't been able to find `IsInstanceOfType` or the equivalent with `Type` or `TypeInfo`. It's very commonly used so I doubt it was dropped completely under the new APIs so I'm betting the functionality has just been renamed or folded together with some other function and I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: This is the first I read about that so maybe it exists in the Reflection API as well, but there is a TypeInfo class (interface?) in the Roslyn API. That being said, you can just use `type(T) == typeof(E)` or `.IsAssignableFrom`

Comment: Equality doesn't work if there's inheritance involved and `IsAssignableFrom` isn't quite the same if someone starts getting crazy with interfaces.

Comment: Im sure  its not the most efficient way but I solved it for the interface type doing something like typeof(MyType).GetTypeInfo().ImplementedInterfaces.Any(i => i == typeof(IMyInterface)) , +few Extensions methods to detect inheritance and/or type equality

Comment: @Dan Does that mean you weren't able to find a way to do it in the default API?

Comment: @BryanAnderson 
Can't remember what on earth possessed me to use typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().ImplementedInterfaces.Any(i => i == typeof(TI)) instead of 
typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TI).GetTypeInfo()) , I guess it could've been the lack of sleep ... or a very valid reason :p,
maybe the semantics of IsAssignableFrom are not as crystal clear as "Do you have this interface ?" kind of question. The truth is... typeinfo.IsAssignableFrom(otherTypeinfo)  should do the trick nicely,

Answer (score 6):

Use this extension method:

```
public static bool IsInstanceOfType(this Type type, object obj){
        return obj != null && type.GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType().GetTypeInfo());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Type foo;
BarType bar;
if(foo.IsInstanceOfType(bar)) { ... }
```

I ended up using

```
Type foo;
BarType bar;
if(bar.GetType() == foo || bar.GetType().GetTypeInfo().IsSubclassOf(foo)) { ... }
```

which seems to work very similarly in most situations.